# Key combo that opens entered url in new tab

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Middle-clicking the "go" button (seen as → in the page address bar) in Firefox opens entered page address in a new tab. Is there a key combination that does the same thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, write the address and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (it works the same for Chrome except it works in empty tabs as well)

Comment: Actually, I think Alt+Enter is sufficient. +1 anyway.

Comment: @jjlin Thanks for the correction, I just updated the answer :D

Comment: This doesn't work on empty tabs, but otherwise it works.

Comment: Note: For Opera its Shift+Enter